# I am Stuck with the error Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found -php pdf creation

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, php-7, mpdf

i've installed `mpdf` library with command `composer require mpdf/mpdf`.And it is installed in the location `vendor/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php`. And `composer_autoload` is `true` in `config\autoload.php`.
with the below code, am getting the error `Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found`. commenting `use Mpdf\Mpdf;` & uncommenting the lines i've commened below shows the error   `require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\abcd\application\controllersvendor/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.

My `php version` is `7.3.3`.

How can i fix this? Can i get some help?

**Controller**

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

use Mpdf\Mpdf;
//use \Mpdf\Mpdf;  //error- Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found

<!--For the below 3, the error/warning is - `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` -->

//require_once __DIR__.'vendor/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php';  
//require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
//include_once('/mpdf/mpdf.php');

class Reports extends Layout_Controller
{
   public function downloadReport(){
        $fileName=$this->input->get('var');
        $mpdf=new Mpdf();
        $html=file_get_contents('reports/'.$fileName);
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $mpdf->Output();
                
    }
}
```

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.7",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "^8.0"
    }
```

Lines commented in this code are what i've tried .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you still have to `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';` above your code.

This file is generated by composer and contains the information of autoloadable classes and the associated files.

Comment: thank you very much. May i ask u y removed directory name from that require statement

Comment: the line `file_get_contents('reports/'.$fileName);` shows the error `file_get_contents(reports/download_advertiser_report_view.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: Can u tell why this error. this file `download_advertiser_report_view.php` exists in the folder `views\reports`

Comment: file_get_contents('views/reports/'.$fileName); ?

Comment: Same error for `file_get_contents('views/reports/'.$fileName);`

Comment: Use full path like this example: `file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../views/reports/'.$fileName);` while `__DIR__` is the directory of your php-file. now you must find out the correct path.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).